# Ajax getting undefined variable in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i want to use ajax for CRUD laravel but when submit button form data save or update in database and return response "**undefined**" value.
**how do i resolve this problem?**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{    
    $user = User::insertGetId([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),

    if ($validated['role'] == 'admin'){
        $user = DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
            'role_id' => 2,
            'model_type' => 'App\User',
            'model_id' => $user,
        ]);
    } else {
        $user = DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
            'role_id' => 1,
            'model_type' => 'App\User',
            'model_id' => $user,
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json($user);

}

public function show($user_id)
{
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    return response()->json($user);
}

public function update(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->first()
        ->update([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);

        if ($request['role'] == 'admin'){
            DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $user_id)->update([
                'role_id' => 2,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user_id,
            ]);
        } else {
            DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $user_id)->update([
                'role_id' => 1,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user_id,
            ]);
        }

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

.....................................................................

Comment: You passed role twice instead of password in the request

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and ***the shortest code necessary*** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also please post your Ajax request, you posted an ajax problem without the ajax

Answer (score 2):

Do your User::insertGetId() exit in the user model? If it does exits, you omitted the semi-colon and the closing bracket. The insertGetId() should receive an argument i.e.

```
$user = User::insertGetId($agr1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

Use $request['role'] instead of $validated['role'] in your store method and make sure your insertGetId() method uses

```
 public function insertGetId($agr1, $agr1, $agr3){
     User::create([
        'name' => $agr1,
        'email' => $arg2,
        'password' => Hash::make($arg3)
       ]);
    }
```